# C# Chart autoscale Y minimum value

Tags: c#, charts

I am having trouble getting the Y axis to autoscale properly using the chart control.  It scales properly in maximum direction, but the minimum is always 0.

I have tried both:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = double.NaN;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
```

Comment: What is your UI framework? WinForms, WPF, Web?

Answer (score 1):

Got it,  the trick was setting

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;
```